# Is @return tag useless with return type declaration

Tags: php, phpdoc, php-7

Is phpdoc's `@return` tag useless with return type declaration? In other words, is there any benefits in `@return` tag in this case:

```
/**
 * Example function.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getOne(): int
{
    return 1;
}
```

Should we remove this annotation in PHP7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should we remove this annotation in PHP7?

While `@return` may look redundant at first glance, it is not. It allows you to put more detailed description about returned value, its meaning, not only type of the value which may be pretty useless in case of more complex data returned (i.e. arrays), therefore I'd rather put some more efforts to make my docs better by using this feature instead of removing `@return` for no real benefit.

Answer (score 1):

If a *class name* is used as the datatype in the @return tag instead of 'int', *phpdoc* will automatically create a link to that class's documentation.

```
/**
 * Example function.
 *
 * @return className
 */
```

Other application, to set descriptive information about multiple returned values:

```
/**
 * Example function.
 *
 * @return int|string could be an int, could be a string 
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

If it returns an int or a boolean your doc should say that it returns an int or boolean.

```
/**
  * @return int 1 on success, 0 means failure
 */
```